# Can't import modules installed on cluster when connecting with databricks-connect

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

## Original question

I'm trying to move from databricks runtime 10.4 LTS to 11.3 LTS. I'm able to connect fine with databricks-connect, but I am not able to import the correct version of the modules that I have loaded on the cluster.

1. I start by creating a new cluster with databricks runtime 11.3 LTS
2. Then I install `pandas==1.5.3` on the cluster with pypi from the *Libraries* tab in the cluster config
3. Wait for the cluster to be ready with installed modules.
4. Then I run the following snippet with databricks-connect:

```py
def test_map(s):
    import pandas as pd

    return pd.__version__


test_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(["test"])
test_rdd.map(test_map).collect()
```

It returns `['1.3.4']`. It should have returned `['1.5.3']`.
When I run the same snippet in a databricks notebook on the same cluster, it returns `['1.5.3']` as expected.

If I follow the steps above for a cluster running 10.4 LTS, the code snippet returns `['1.5.3']` with both databricks-connect and in a databricks notebook.

If I try to install a module on 11.3 LTS that is not part of the databricks runtime by default, e.g. `openpyxl`, and importing it with databricks-connect as above, I get an exception `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'`. With a standard databricks notebook, the module gets imported fine.

I run `databricks-connect==10.4.22` when connecting to 10.4 LTS.

I run `databricks-connect==11.3.10`  when connecting to 11.3 LTS

How can I make the installed modules available through databricks-connect when running databricks runtime 11.3 LTS?

## Further investigation:

To diagnose the problem further, I tried running the following snippet in both databricks-connect and standard databricks notebook:

```py
def test_map(s):
    import sys

    return sys.executable


test_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(["test"])
test_rdd.map(test_map).collect()
```

The idea is to see whether the same python environment is used in both cases. The following tables shows what the snippet returns:

|  | 10.4 LTS | 11.3 LTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Databricks notebook** | `['/databricks/python/bin/python']` | `['/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/bin/python']` |
| **Databricks-connect** | `['/databricks/python/bin/python']` | `['/databricks/python/bin/python']` |

The 11.3 LTS columns hints that the modules are missing because databricks-connect is running in a different python environment than plain databricks notebooks.

## Trying out proposed answer:

I tried following the suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75966615/13106037) answer without luck.

1. I start by extracting the versions of all installed packages on the cluster by running:

   ```
   %sh pip freeze
   ```

   in a databricks notebook.
2. I then copy the list of packages and versions to a local
   `requirements.txt` and run

   ```
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```

   to install the correct version of the packages locally.
   I was not able to install the following packages, but I don't think
   they are needed:

   ```
   distro-info===0.23ubuntu1
   python-apt==2.0.1
   unattended-upgrades==0.1
   PyGObject==3.36.0
   dbus-python==1.2.16
   Pygments==2.10.0d
   ```
3. Then I ran the suggested [script](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/blob/main/dbconnect-package-versions-check/package_versions_check.py) locally with databricks-connect.
   I got no output, which verifies that the local and cluster packages
   are now the same version.
4. Then I install `pandas==1.5.3` with pypi on the cluster from the
   *Libraries* tab in the cluster config.
5. Then I install `pandas==1.5.3` locally by changing the pandas line in
   `requirements.txt` to `pandas==1.5.3` and then running

   ```
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```
6. Then I again run the suggested [script](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/blob/main/dbconnect-package-versions-check/package_versions_check.py) locally with databricks-connect, and get the following output:

   ```
   Version mismatch for packate pandas! Remote: 1.3.4, Local: 1.5.3
   ```

I am still not able to install another version of pandas. Also, when installing `openpyxl` on the cluster, it does not show up in the [`remote_pkgs`](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/blob/main/dbconnect-package-versions-check/package_versions_check.py#L15) variable in the [script](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/blob/main/dbconnect-package-versions-check/package_versions_check.py#L15). The output from `%sh pip freeze` running in a databricks notebook reports it as installed.
Unfortunately, nothing seems to have changed from my original question.

Answer (score 0):

With Databricks Connect, your local machine runs a Spark driver, and main code is running locally, so you need to have the same packages installed locally.  And versions of the packages should match, otherwise you may get strange errors.  You can use [following script](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/tree/main/dbconnect-package-versions-check) to check if versions on your local machine & executors match.